# Jenkins job fails to remove directory

Tags: jenkins

I am running make script(Execute Shell command option) inside a jenkins job.
The make script has `rm -rf <directory name>` shell command. 
This command fails with error saying the Directory is not empty. Since script uses `rm -rf` it should work even if directory is not empty.
Not sure what is wrong here. 
Any help around this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If your Jenkins job is executed on a Linux machine, this could b:

- a [permission issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/566820/5470).
- a [race condition issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12627/7490) (which is [why deleting files first](https://askubuntu.com/a/665534/5470) is a good idea. Then your `rm -Rf` will delete all the empty folders)

On Windows, check the full error message: there could be a resource preempted by the OS (used by another process).

Comment: Its a Linux Box.<br/> I can see that workspace directory are owned by user "jenkinsutil" and the job is being run by user "projectutil". <br/> Is there a way I can make sure the job can run the mentioned command on directory owned by other user?

Comment: @Sandeep OK, so the first three links (from the first two points) are relevant.

Comment: yes. I think I can change the permission for the files downloaded in jenkins workspace before the script runs. I will give this a try.

Comment: Hi I tried adding permissions to the directory being deleted still the rm -rf command fails with same message. Not sure what is wrong. The same command works fine on local machine

Comment: @Sandeep Can you try with `rm -Rf` instead of `rm -rf`?

Comment: I can't as code is pulled from repo where I cannot make changes but same command works for other folder. Here is build output -                                      ADD proxy /test
  Using cache
RUN rm -rf /test/.classpath /test/.gitignore /test/.gradle /test/.project /test/.settings /test/Dockerfile /test/build
RUN cd /test; ./gradlew oneJar
RUN rm -rf /test/src
[91mrm: cannot remove ‘/test/src/main/java/prj/java/action’: Directory not empty
The command '/bin/sh -c rm -rf /test/src' returned a non-zero code:

Comment: @Sandeep so it might not be a permission issue, but some kind of race issue, here the folder is still being used by the previous command I suppose

Comment: That might be happening. Command before the rm -rf which fails is a build command which compiles code to same directory. Is there any way to wait for this build command to finish and then only execute em -rf command?

Answer (score 0):

You can first try and empty the directory and then delete the directory.

Try running the following command:

```
rm mydir/* mydir/.* 
rmdir mydir
```

Comment: On a Windows environment this should be "rmdir 'mydir' /S /Q" to force deleting all contents and the directory itself it without asking, but the original quesiton looks like it was a Linux sceario, no idea how to do that